# IIS 7 not showing errors in Classic ASP. IIS 6 Does

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, iis-6

We have a legacy website written in classic asp. We had it hosted on iis6. Whenever there was an error it would send the details and description of the error to the client.

Thing is that after we moved it to IIS7, some "errors" would not show up. for example

```
<% 
sdfkjlsfjl
%>
```

this would trigger an error on iis6, but on iis7 it would simple show an blank screen.
in the other hand if i do this

```
<%
if a=1
end if
%>
```

it would throw in both server an error regarding the missing 'Then'

has anybody faced this before?

thanks

Comment: If you're getting a blank screen (and not even a default 500 error screen) it sounds like classic ASP hasn't been installed. IIS7 doesn't include a classic ASP handler by default: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/562/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis/

Answer (score 4):

In IIS7 you need to enable client-side debugging for ASP.

1. Open IIS Manager
2. In Features View, double-click ASP.
3. in there you will see a "Debugging Properties" section
4. Change from False to True on the properties you want to change.
5. Restart IIS
6. Test to see if the errors are now being sent to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce the behaviour you describe on IIS7.

However I suspect what you will actually have in your code is a `On Error Resume Next`.  This traps **runtime** errors such as your first sample code.  However your second sample contains a **compilation** error.  Syntax errors are not trappable, script won't even begin to execute.  Instead ASP throws the compilation error back to IIS in a 500.100 state.

Another less likely possiblity is that you have response buffering turned off and some previous  strange content already sent to the browser is making the error invisible (try using view source to confirm that).

Answer (score 0):

In **IIS**, under **Features**...**ASP**...**Debugging Properties**:

Set **Enable Server-side debugging** to **False**. This will cure the blank screen of death.

If you want to see the actual error rather than *An error occurred on the server...* then

set **Send Errors to Browser** to **True**.